# upload error when create downloadable product

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, downloadable

I'm new for Magento. When I upload file in Product details as 'Downloadable Product', It's uploading fully and showing 100%. But when I click, 'Save' it's giving alert as

```
There are files that were selected but not uploaded yet.
Please upload or remove them first.
```

Actually file size 70MB. If I upload small file, here No problem.

Comment: please check your media folder permission and increase your file upload limit in php.ini

Comment: @KeyulShah No use. I changed in php.ini and as well as .htaccess

Comment: you are using linux OS or Windows OS

Comment: Windows only using

Comment: I again check it will working in my pc local magento you do some mistake to upload file

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an upload size issue.
Even if it's stated in the comments that the value in php.ini has been changed, check if you modified the right `php.ini`.  A fast way to check the max size of the uploaded files is to go to `System->Import/Export->Import`.
You should see a message at the top of the page saying:

> Total size of uploadable files must not exceed ....M

Comment: Not working. 128M is written there but it accepts only upto 3 mb